Overloading resolution - match through const conversion is considered exact match?
void f(int) {}

void f(const int&) {}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    f(i);
}

I get an ambiguous call here, what am I missing? I'm using GCC 11.2.0 with -std=c++11.
I'm reading C++ Primer 5th Edition, 6.6.1 Argument Type Conversions:

Conversions are ranked as follows:

An exact match. An exact match happens when:

The argument and parameter types are identical.
The argument is converted from an array or function type to the corresponding pointer type.
A top-level const is added to or discarded from the argument.


Match through a const conversion.


According to the book f(int) should have higher priority because it is an exact match.

afaik because i is an lvalue, its type is deduced as int&. If you were to call f(0), that would be an exact match of f(int)

Just being pragmatic/opinionated: both functions can receive int i;, so they're inherently ambiguous, even if you use overload resolution as a crutch. This can be desirable in situations where you're essentially templating a function, but otherwise you're making life difficult.

@chrysante f(0) is also an ambiguous call

@TedLyngmo Still ambiguous

@Neox No, it's not: demo

@TedLyngmo I tested f(i) with all the three versions. Without the int version it is indeed ok

@chrysante Nothing is "deduced" here.

@Neox See this answer in the dupe.
